# Automatically reload .vimrc in multiple sessions

Tags: vim

I usually develop with vim open in multiple tabs/terminals. When I make a change to my vimrc, this means closing and reopening all sessions of vim. Is there a way to automatically reload your vimrc in ALL open sessions? It seems like if this was possible, the answer would be easy to find, but I thought I would ask anyway.

I've already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158277). As the answer suggests, it doesn't work for regular vim (only gvim)

Comment: Whether console Vim supports message passing depends on build configuration. If you want to use it in console Vim, just build it with `clientserver` feature turned on. See the question that Connor suggests in his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231223/compile-vim-7-3-with-clientserver-feature-on-mac-os-x) about clientserver on a Mac (assuming this might be your problem).

Answer (score 1):

You can reload your vimrc without exiting vim:

```
:source ~/.vimrc
```

But you'll need to do this across all open instances of vim.

Comment: I know you can do this, but I was looking for a more magical way. Also, IIRC this won't work 100% of the time because it doesn't unmap anything. If there was an automatic method you could add in a :mapclear with it.