# vim is not resourcing the .vimrc file until exiting the program

Tags: macos, vim

i have asked this question and so far nobody seems to be able to come up with a reasonable reason as to why my resource file is not being resourced.
`:source $MYVIMRC` `:so ~/.vimrc`

```
 au BufWritePost .vimrc source ~/.vimrc
```

`:echo $MYVIMRC` == `/Users/******/.vimrc`. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated as a week to having this problem (new mac) i am having to exit vim and re enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there can be a possible problem with how the files are called within each platform. Try cross-platform solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403926/5154907):

```
au BufWritePost .vimrc,_vimrc,vimrc,.gvimrc,_gvimrc,gvimrc so $MYVIMRC | if has('gui_running') && filereadable($MYGVIMRC) | so $MYGVIMRC | endif
```

or better

```
augroup myvimrc
    au!
    au BufWritePost .vimrc,_vimrc,vimrc,.gvimrc,_gvimrc,gvimrc so $MYVIMRC | if has('gui_running') && filereadable($MYGVIMRC) | so $MYGVIMRC | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: what little hair i had left has been lost over this. lol. thanks works perfectly the `augroup func`