# How to reload vim/gvim config in all running instances from outside vim/gvim

Tags: bash, vim

So for example, i would have a command i could run from a bash script, and all open gvim and vim sessions would reload their config.

This is already the whole question, really, but I will also include my specific issue:

I want to be able to change between a light and a dark theme on the fly from a script.
i have these files in *~/*:

```
.vimrc             # contains "source ~/.vimrc_theme"
.vimrc_theme       # is a symbolic link to either of the following two files
.vimrc_theme_light # contains "colorscheme morning"
.vimrc_theme_dark  # contains "colorscheme evening"
```

and my theme-changer script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# should be either "light" or "dark"
_mode=${1:-light}

cd \
    && rm .vimrc_theme \
    && ln -s .vimrc_theme_${_mode} .vimrc_theme \
    && touch .vimrc \
    && touch .gvimrc
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400264/is-it-possible-to-apply-vim-configurations-without-restarting) deals with a similar thing. There, one wants to edit *.vimrc* from inside vim, and then reload it. I want to trigger a reload from the outside.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but following '[One Vim ... just one* - Using One Vim session is the way to go](http://vimeo.com/4446112)' would also simplify your question to the link you referenced.

Comment: it states there, that this only works for gvim, not vim, and even so, as much as i know, the question i linked to has answers that rely on methods that only work vim internal, as much as i know (and as a few quick tests confirmed). meaning: if only reloads the configuration if the config file was changed in vim, within the same session.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar works with

```
mkfifo mypipe
```

And custom,

```
watch -color...
```

But that's suitable for textual sharing.
Alternatively, you could write to some tmpfile from your bash script, and put some sort of loop that reads it as part of vimenter autocmd to then run your internal command.